# import function from another file in colab not working

Tags: import, google-colaboratory, kora

I am trying to import a function from another file different directory in Colab, but it's not working.

I have tried:

1)

```
!pip install kora -q 
from kora import drive
drive.link_nbs()
```

2. 

```
sys.path(0,"path to file")
import name_file
```

3. 

```
import ipynb
```